# How to Create Combination of Element in Different Set?

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Let say that I have n lists and they are not disjoint. I want to make every combination of n elements which I get one from every lists I have but in that combination there are different elements and there are no double combination. So, `[1,1,2]` isn't allowed and `[1,2,3]` is same as `[2,1,3]`.

For example, I have `A=[1,2,3]`, `B=[2,4,1]`, and `C=[1,5,3]`. So, the output that I want is `[[1,2,5],[1,2,3],[1,4,5],[1,4,3],[2,4,1],[2,4,5],[2,4,3],[3,2,5],[3,4,5],[3,1,5]]`.

I have search google and I think function `product` in module `itertools` can do it. But, I have no idea how to make no same elements in every combinations and no double combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
from itertools import product                                               
A=[1,2,3]
B=[2,4,1]
C=[1,5,3]
L = list(set([ tuple(sorted(l)) for l in product(A,B,C) if len(set(l))==3 ]))
```

Of course you would have to change `3` ot the relevant value if you work with more than 3 lists.

Comment: There are combinations that have double elemen such as `(1,2,1)` and I don't want that.

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you very much! This is what I want.

Comment: By the way, what's the purpose of `sorted`?

Comment: this returns `(2, 3, 5)` as an element; but `3` does not appear as second
element in any list. ..not sure if that is a requirement though.

Comment: @fahadh4ilyas `sorted(l)` will sort each combination, thus mapping `(2,4,1)` to `(1,2,4)` allowing to later discard duplicates with `set`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist You are right, but since `(1,2,4)` and `(2,4,1)` seem to be duplicates according to the question, I think it doesn't matter if the resulting tuples are sorted. Regards.

Comment: that is a convincing argument...! +1

Comment: What if I have a list `A=[[1,2,3],[2,4,1],[1,5,3],...]` and I want to make `len(A)` combination of `A[0]`, `A[1]`, `A[2]`, ..., `A[len(A)-1]`? I can't write `product(A[0],A[1],A[2],...,A[len(A)-1])` because `len(A)` based on user input.

Comment: @fahadh4ilyas Try something like:  `product(*A)` Regards.

Comment: Thank you! It really help me.

Answer (score 0):

how about this? create a dicitonary with the sorted permutations as key. accept values only if all the three integers are different:

```
from itertools import product
A=[1,2,3]
B=[2,4,1]
C=[1,5,3]

LEN = 3

dct = {tuple(sorted(item)): item for item in product(A,B,C) 
       if len(set(item)) == LEN}

print(dct)
vals = list(dct.values())
print(vals)
```